# Using cut in Linux Mint Terminal more precisely

Tags: linux, terminal

In the directory /usr/lib on Linux Mint there are files, among other things, that goes by the name of xxx.so.d where xxx is their name, and d being a number. The assignment is to find all files with .so file ending and write out their name, xxx. The code I got so far is

```
ls | grep "\.so\." | cut -d "." -f 1
```

The problem now is that cut cuts of some filenames short, as an example there is an file called libgimp-2.0.so.0, where the wanted output would be libgimp-2.0 since that part is infront of .so
Is there anyway to make cut cut at ".so" instead of the first .?

Comment: What can you use besides `cut`?

Comment: I wouldn't know, had my first class today and really no experience

Comment: I can use what ever I want I believe, just should be efficient

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.so*; do echo "${i%.so*}"; done
```

just a bash parameter substitution
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by pacholik can give you wrong files (ie: 'xyz.socket' will appear on your list). To correct his script:

```
for i in *.so.*; do echo "${i%%.so*}"; done
```

Another way to do this (easier to read in my opinion) is to use a little Perl:

```
 ls | grep "\.so\." | perl -n0e "print ((split(/\.so/))[0], \"\n\")"
```

Sorry, I don't think there is a way to use only "cut" as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed instead:

```
ls | grep -v ".socket" | grep .so | sed "s/.so.*//"
```

This will delete everything behind the first found `.so` in the file names. So also files named `xxx.so.so` would work.

Comment: Again files named "xyz.socket" would appear with this solution. This solution corrected would be: ls | grep "\.so\." | sed "s/.so.*//"

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. I changed it and added an exclusion. With "\.so\." it would also work and answers the question perfectly, but the exclusion is a bit more variably usable.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the size of the directory probably using [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) could be the best option, as a start point give a try to this:

```
find . -iname "*.so.*" -exec basename {} \;  | cut -d "." -f 1
```

Like `cut` there are many other options, like [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) that could help you achieve in some cases the same result in a faster way.